# Iterating over files in a folder in a specific order?

Tags: c#, loops

I am very new to c# programming, so if my question is trivial I apologize.
I am running some c# code where I need to iterate over some files in a folder and am using:

```
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\GeneralStats"))
{
```

However, I would like to have these files read in a specific order according to file name. My file names are of the below format.

```
generalstats_2012_11_1.csv
generalstats_2012_11_2.csv
generalstats_2012_11_3.csv
.....
```

When my code reads in the files it starts with generalstats_2012_11_1.csv but then jumps directly to generalstats_2012_11_10.csv, instead of generalstats_2012_11_2.csv.

I have tried searching the web for answers but have been unable to find any. I of course ordered the files according to date  (in the name) in the specific folder, but the code does not acknowledge that at all.
Can anyone help me - is there some order function in c# that I have missed?

Comment: Search for `human sort` or `natural sort order`

Comment: Use two digits for your months and days! Or have fun implementing a [natural sort](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Natural Sort Order in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp). (The question isn't great but the top answer should be a solution for you - it basically shows how to order the files using the same underlying function that Windows does.)

Comment: Seems a bit odd to go to the trouble of writing dates in YMD order and then use single digits for the days... I'd fix that rather than piddle about with natural sort order.

Comment: Thanks guys, I really appreciate your help and very fast replies. What worked for me was the answer from Ivan G :-)

Comment: @LeneJungKjær - that's what the "tick" option next to Ivan's answer is for - so you can indicate that your question is answered.

Comment: Ok, Sorry - I am new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
        var paths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\GeneralStats")
            .OrderBy(path => 
                Convert.ToInt32(path.Split('_', '.')[1]) * 10000 + 
                Convert.ToInt32(path.Split('_', '.')[2]) * 100 + 
                Convert.ToInt32(path.Split('_', '.')[3]));

        foreach (string path in paths)
        {
        }
```

This gets the date parts from the file name and creates an integer out of them, for example `2012_11_10` from file name is 2012110 as integer, `2012_11_1` is 20121101 etc. These numbers are used for sorting.

Another variation of the above approach would be:

```
        var paths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\GeneralStats")
            .OrderBy(path =>
                Convert.ToInt32(
                    String.Concat(
                        path.Split('_', '.')
                            .Skip(1)
                            .Take(3)
                            .Select(num => num.PadLeft(2, '0'))
                            .ToArray())
                )
            );
```

It also parses numbers from file names and creates integers used for sorting.

Instead of `Directory.GetFiles` method you can use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` (but this is available only in .NET 4 and higher versions).

Comment: Does the second idea correctly deal with 2012_1_11 vs 2012_11_1 ?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone I don't think it does, that's why I removed it:) Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: I fixed the sort for the second version with `PadLeft(2, '0')` which adds '0' in front of one-digit months or days (years are not affected).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to order by the date behind the file-name you have to cast it to one, otherwise the order is alphabetically(therefore "10" is before "2").

You can use `Enumerable.OrderBy` in this linq-query:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\temp\GeneralStats", "*.csv")
    .Select(fn => new
    {
        Path = fn,
        Split = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn).Split('_')
    })
    .Where(x => x.Split.Length == 4)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.Path,
        Date = new DateTime(int.Parse(x.Split[1]), int.Parse(x.Split[2]), int.Parse(x.Split[3]))
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
    .Select(x => x.Path);
```

First i'm selecting an anonymous type with some useful properties from the `Path` class like `GetFileNameWithoutExtension`. That will make the rest of the query more efficient and more readable. The `Where` is to prevent errors when there are files which don't have the date part in the file-name. The next select parses the `DateTime` from the tokens derived from `string.Split`. The last three parts contain the year, month and day. The `OrderBy` will order by the date. Finally i select again the full-path since you originally wanted to order the files.

You can enumerate the result with a `foreach` or use e.g. `ToList` if you want to persist it:

```
foreach (string f in files)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it - I couldn't quite get that to work but the below answer from Ivan G solved it for me.

Comment: @LeneJungKjær: Maybe you are on .NET 3.5, `EnumerateFiles` requires .NET framework 4, then simply replace it with `GetFiles` which reads all files into memory first. The rest works also on 3.5.